# Can anyone other than web client calculate the fingerprint of a digital certificate? And figure out CA’s private key from fingerprint signature pairs?

Tags: ssl, certificate, rsa, x509certificate, x509

I had a random question while trying to understand digital certificate.

From what I understand, a web server sends a CSR to a CA, which contains web server’s RSA public key and identity (subject, CN etc.). CA adds some more information (e.g. issuer, validity dates), signs this CSR with the RSA private key of CA and thus prepares a digital certificate.
More simply, this is what follows -

1. Create the certificate content (Client’s public key, Subject, Issuer, Validity dates etc.)
2. Creating HASH of the above certificate content (fingerprint)
3. Create signature by encrypting only the HASH (not the entire certificate content) and append this signature to the above certificate content and thus prepare a digital certificate.

(kind of like this one - [Digital certificate creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVYns.jpg)

**Am I correct in understanding the creation process of a digital certificate?**

If that’s so,
the certificate contents (except signature part) seems totally un-encrypted and thereby can be read by anybody between a client and web server. Thus every device between client and webserver should be able to read the fingerprint  and signature. Now that –

```
Fingerprint of certificate (HASH) + CA’s private key = encrypted text (Signature)
```

**Is there a possibility that somebody can take lots and lots of packet trace of certificates transferred, calculate the fingerprint himself for each certs, create a lot of pairs of fingerprints and signature pairs and find out the CA’s private key by some sort of reverse calculation?**

Thanks ..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to security.sx

Answer (score 3):

0. This is not about programming (and I agree to delete this if necessary to close or delete)
1. Digital signature is NOT "encrypting with the private key". This is a wrong idea that was popular about 40 years ago, but still lingers because people keep copying it. See my https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/159282/can-openssl-decrypt-the-encrypted-signature-in-an-amazon-alexa-request- .
2. Web servers, and other SSL/TLS servers, and CAs also, are not limited to RSA. Several other signing algorithms are possible, and currently ECDSA is becoming fairly common. It is fairly common for CAs to use the same algorithm for the cert as the subject's key, i.e. to sign a cert containing an RSA key with an RSA key or one containing an ECDSA key with an ECDSA key, but this is not technically necessary (and 1.3 supports *separate* negotiations for the server *or* client sigalgs and the certificate sigalgs, which earlier protocols did not).
3. The fingerprint of a cert, by convention, is the hash of the whole cert including the signature, not the hash of the signed part which is used in the digital signature computation.
4. But yes, certificates are designed to be public and can be read by anybody. (For TLS 1.3 the certificate transmission is encrypted so a totally passive eavesdropper can't read it, but a minimally active attacker can simply do their own connection and get the cert(s).) Even the signature can be verified by anybody. For RSA *only*, verifying the signature involves recovering (not decrypting) and comparing the hash, but even without that anyone can compute the hash of the signed part.
5. For any signature scheme to be considered acceptable in the past 50 years or so, knowing signatures for valid data, even attacker-chosen data, must not allow *either* recovering the key *nor* forging a signature for different data (that the attacker wants) which would be just as bad for security. RSA as currently used as acceptable, although one scheme (block type 0) in early PKCS1v1 last century was not. ECDSA is acceptable *if* appropriately random 'k' values are used, or instead deterministic but key-dependent ones (see RFC6979 and a dozens of Qs on crypto.SX and security.SX where this is ontopic). However, if two ECDSA signatures are known (for known data) using the same key and k the private key can be recovered; there are also numerous existing Qs on this, including on bitcoin.SX because it occurred on some Bitcoin implementations (look for either "same/duplicate k" or "same/duplicate r" because one component of the ECDSA signature, r, is computed directly from the scalar multiplication `kG`).